# xml value shown in combo box

Tags: xml, vb.net

```xml
<DataSet1>
  <DataTable1>
    <NAME>A/NAME>
    <VEHICLENO>123</VEHICLENO>
    <MOBILE>345</MOBILE>
  </DataTable1>
  <DataTable1>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <VEHICLENO>123</VEHICLENO>
    <MOBILE>555</MOBILE>
  </DataTable1>
</DataSet1>
```

I have xml code shown like above. I have 2 ComboBoxes combobox1 and 2. If I write name "A" in combobox1 the corresponding combobox value related only A related "DRIVER INFO" value to be shown in second combo box, please how to make this in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml serialization and databinding

First, make some classes to represent your data

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

```vb
<XmlRoot>
Public Class DataSet1
    <XmlElement("DataTable1")>
    Public DataTable1s As List(Of DataTable1)
End Class

Public Class DataTable1
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property NAME As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property VEHICLENO As String
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property MOBILE As String
End Class
```

Since I don't know where your xml comes from, I'm going to use a vb.net xml literal for convenience. If it's in a file you should use a FileStream instead.

```vb
Private dataset As DataSet1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim xml =
        <DataSet1>
            <DataTable1>
                <NAME>A</NAME>
                <VEHICLENO>123</VEHICLENO>
                <MOBILE>345</MOBILE>
            </DataTable1>
            <DataTable1>
                <NAME>B</NAME>
                <VEHICLENO>123</VEHICLENO>
                <MOBILE>555</MOBILE>
            </DataTable1>
        </DataSet1>

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataSet1))
    ' Using sr As New StreamReader("path.xml")
    Using sr = xml.CreateReader()
        dataset = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(sr), DataSet1)
    End Using

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dataset.DataTable1s.Select(Function(dt) dt).ToList()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME"
End Sub
```

When the first ComboBox index is changed, it updates the second.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedDataTable1 = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, DataTable1)
    ComboBox2.DataSource = {selectedDataTable1.NAME, selectedDataTable1.VEHICLENO, selectedDataTable1.MOBILE}.ToList()
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming all the xml properties are strings. If not, update the model I provided and do the appropriate conversions in the combobox binding.

Comment: thanks for your great support ,,